# Integration Application Express 5 and E-Business Suite 11.5.10

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-ebs

Need your help.
How to make a link from E-Business Suite 11i to ApEx5.
Mostly the articles talk about E-Business Suite 12.X
I was follow this doc from Rod West.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/apex-ebs-wp-cabot-consulting-169064.pdf

My Link always back to EBS index page. ( Login Page ).

Your reply more appreciated.

Need help.

Thanks and regards

M.C